# Combine the background image position in the element with position in the image sprites

Tags: css, css-position

I have an element (h3) and I want to set background position to the right, it's easy:

```
background: url('/images/icon-popular.png') no-repeat right center;
```

But I want to use .png file where I have a lot of other icons (Image Sprites), usually I do:

```
background-image: url('/images/icons-info.png');
background-position: 0 -110px;
```

How can I merge the background-position in the file with "right center" position in the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar thread like yours: [Using Css Sprites and background position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444358/using-css-sprites-and-background-position)

But personally what I'll do to achieve this effect to use a pseudo selector like `h3:before`, style it to match the size of the icon in the sprite and position that element to the right of the `h3`.

```
h3 {
    background-color: #faa;
    padding:5px 10px;
}

h3:before {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 35px;
    height: 23px;
    background: transparent url('https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3sdj4tga/

The possible issue with your approach is if an `h3` takes more space than what you have allotted in your sprite, the other parts of the image will show up giving an undesirable effect.